# Why Django requires "_id" in the name of ForeignKey field?

Tags: python, django, database

I have models for players, teams and matches. Obviously, that I have some ForeignKey field. But if I don't add "_id" in the end of ForeignKey field, Django raises the error: "no such column: betbot_testmatch.leftTeam_id"

I have tried to add "_id" in the end of my ForeignKey fields and it really solved the problem, but in my previous project I designed, I have been usin FK fields without any "_id" in the end of field names and there were no problems.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class TestMatch(models.Model):
    leftTeam = models.ForeignKey('TestTeam', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+', default='Left Team')
    rightTeam = models.ForeignKey('TestTeam', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+', default='Right Team')

class TestTeam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Team')
    urlslug = models.SlugField(max_length=5)



class TestPlayer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Player')
    nick = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Nickname')
    team_id = models.ForeignKey('TestTeam', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default='Team')
    #photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='', null=True)
    No = 'N'
    Yes = 'Y'
    STANDIN_CHOICES = [
        (Yes, 'Yes'),
        (No, 'No'),
    ]
    standin = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=STANDIN_CHOICES, default=No)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=20, default=nick)
```

I want that I could use my names for ForeignKey field without the mistake.

Comment: Hey @KochetovMXM are you sure you have run your migrations properly once after changing the structure of your models?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `ForeignKey` field on a model, Django does a few things under the hood

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CACSCADE)
```

Every instance of `Foo` now has two attributes

```
foo = Foo()

# This is a descriptor that will perform a DB lookup for the
# related model and return it or raise an exception
foo.bar

# This will return the actual value stored in the database
# that is used by the descriptor to lookup the related model
# by default this will be the id
foor.bar_id
```

Comment: I understand it, but the problem is that if I don't add "_id" in the end of the field name, then django raises the error "no such column: betbot_testmatch.leftTeam_id"

Comment: As bikash said. Have you run your migrations?

Comment: Sure I did, I checked my last project, django didn't ask for "_id" there

Comment: If I have changes they applies

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. The thing was that in the TestMatch wasn't any fields but ForeignKey, so Django couldn't create id for it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. By default, Django gives each model an id field. This is an auto-incrementing primary key.  see:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields